Ultrasonic Mist Maker
I'm attempting to build an Ultrasonic Mist Maker following a tutorial and diagrams, primarily from this Instructables guide https://www.instructables.com/DIY-MISTFOG-MAKER-USING-IC-555/ . However, as an electronics beginner, I've run into some confusion regarding the connections for the R1 potentiometer and the R2 10-ohm resistor.
Specifically:
Does R2 connect to pin 3 of the potentiometer or directly to pin 3 of the 555 IC?
Where exactly does pin 3 of the potentiometer connect in the circuit?
Any clarification on this would be greatly appreciated!


R1 is wired as a variable resistor,  not as a potentiometer

Usually, I see the end terminals of the potentiometer resistance element numbered 1 and 3, with the wiper (moving contact) as pin 2 as the pins are usually in that order on the pot.
Regardless of the numbering, you want the wiper and one end of the resistance element connected to the 555's pin 3 and to the left end of R2.  The actual routing of the connections between these four terminals doesn't matter, as long as they are connected together.
